# c# large doubles comparison

Tags: c#, comparison, largenumber

Let me start right off by saying this isn't a question about **decimal precision tolerance comparision**! This is more of an issue of the inherent representation of large doubles in that after a certain range the computer starts losing significat presicion and not on the decimal side. E.g.

```
double d1 = 1e20+8000;
double d2 = 1e20;
Debug.WriteLine(d1 == d2);
```

Now this yields true which for me is very unacceptable. Converting to decimal at this point in the project is out of the question. Is there a way to mitigate this for example computing somehow that at ^20 the computer represents numbers ^20 +- 8000 the same? The tolerance seems to be 8000 for this exponent going above it triggers correct comparison but I need exact comparison up to the decimal point, beyond that i don't care for large numbers.

Comment: I recommend reading ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic
"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 7):

> Now this yields true which for me is very unacceptable.

Then you should use a data type that does what you want. You should never use floating point precision numbers when you expect accuracy. `decimal` is what you should use.

Changing data types is your only option that works on the long term. If you don't want to go there, there is no option that would not need a significant amount of work on checking the calculations made.